# SAS SQL: WHERE LIKE 'list of words'

Tags: sql, sas

I've a dataset that has some comments that would exclude subjects. I want to make a mini dataset to collect these subjects.

I'm trying to use SAS SQL for this so I tried to do this:

```
  PROC SQL;
         CREATE TABLE EXCLUDE as
         SELECT *
         FROM data_set
         WHERE UPCASE(COMMENT) like '%(INELIGIBLE | REFUSED)%';
 QUIT;
```

I also tried

```
 PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE exclude as
    SELECT *
     FROM Data_set
        WHERE UPCASE(COMMENT) like ('%INELIGIBLE%'|'%REFUSED%')
    ;
 QUIT;
```

I keep getting an error that says 'LIKE OPERATOR Requires character operands'

How can I make this a proper syntax query?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Keep/exclude comments that contain 'Ineligible' and 'Refused'? If so, simply break up in `OR`/`AND` statements with `LIKE` operator.

Comment: The like operator is not for regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it via a like-join against a list of the terms to exclude :

```
data words ;
  input word $char16. ;
datalines ;
INELIGABLE
REFUSED
;
run ;

proc sql ;
  create table exclude as
  select a.*
  from data_set a
       left join
       words b on upcase(a.comment) like cats('%',b.word,'%')
  where missing(b.word) ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl regular expressions to do this, if you're working with a string that already is formed.  (If not, you're better off just writing the separate syntax, PRXs are slow.)

Equivalent code here, one written out, one with a PRX using a single string:

```
proc sql;
  select * 
  from sashelp.class
  where not (name like 'A%' or name like 'B%');
quit;


proc sql;
  select * 
  from sashelp.class
  where not (prxmatch('~^[A|B]~io',name));
quit;
```

Comment: I've never used pearl before. what does ~ mean?

Comment: The `~` character there is just the regex delimiter

Answer (score 2):

SQL does not have full regular expressions support.  In SAS, you could use `prxmatch()`.  But, you can also do this in SQL:

```
  PROC SQL;
     CREATE TABLE EXCLUDE as
         SELECT *
         FROM data_set
         WHERE UPCASE(COMMENT) like '%INELIGIBLE%' OR
               UPCASE(COMMENT) like '%REFUSED)%';
  QUIT;
```

Note:  this will not use an index on `comment`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, using `contains`, where the search terms comes from a dataset (which can e.g. be read from external file). I like this for its portability.

```
Proc sql noprint;
      select 'Upcase(Comment) contains '''||strip(Upcase(term))||''''
      into :strings separated by ' or '
      from exclusion_terms
      order by 1;

      create table Excluded as
      select *
      from Data_set
      where &strings;
Quit;
```

Here, the first section creates the macro variable `string` from the dataset of exclusion terms, which is then used to create the Excluded dataset.

The hard-coded version version of search terms using `Contains`:

```
Proc Sql;
      create table Excluded as
      select *
      from Data_set
      where Upcase(Comment) contains ('INELIGIBLE' OR 'REFUSED');
Quit;
```